# SQL - How to find if the combination of column has occured before or not?

Tags: sql, performance, presto, exists

Following example demonstrates the question

| id | location | dt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | India | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | Usa | 2020-02-01 |
| 1 | Usa | 2020-03-01 |
| 3 | China | 2020-04-01 |
| 1 | India | 2020-05-01 |
| 2 | France | 2020-06-01 |
| 1 | India | 2020-07-01 |
| 2 | Usa | 2020-08-01 |

This table is sorted by date.
I want to create another column, which would tell if the id has been to the location before or not.

So, The output would be like

| id | location | dt | travelled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | India | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 2 | Usa | 2020-02-01 | 0 |
| 1 | Usa | 2020-03-01 | 0 |
| 3 | China | 2020-04-01 | 0 |
| 1 | India | 2020-05-01 | 1 |
| 2 | France. | 2020-06-01 | 0 |
| 1 | India | 2020-07-01 | 1 |
| 2 | Usa | 2020-08-01 | 1 |

The issue I am facing is, For every row, I need to consider only the rows above it.

Comment: What stop you to figure out?

Comment: For any row, I need to consider only the rows above it. This is the part that I am not able to fix

Comment: What is *the row above it* ? Do these rows have numbers?

Comment: Table also has a date column. So, to see if the id has travelled to the location before or not I need to consider the rows above(Past datest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` in a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.location,
       CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS (
           SELECT 1 
           FROM tablename t2 
           WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.location = t1.location AND t2.date < t1.date 
         ) THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END travelled
FROM tablename t1
```

Comment: `EXISTS` yields a boolean; you don't need the `CASE` expression.

Comment: @wildplasser if the OP needs a boolean then it is not needed. If the result should be 1 or 0 then I guess it is.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend window functions for this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by id, location order by date) > 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as travelled
from t;
```

Window functions are usually faster than alternative methods.